# convert all TINYINT fields to INTEGER in jooq

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I want to convert all my TINYINT fields generated in jooq to Integer types. this is my code but its not working. anyone with a clue

```
    <forcedTypes>
      <forcedType>
        <name>INTEGER</name>
        <types>TINYINT</types>
      </forcedType>
    </forcedTypes>
```

this is what is generated

```
public final TableField<GroupsRecord, Byte> FY_TYPE = createField(DSL.name("fy_type"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.TINYINT.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.inline("0", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.TINYINT)), this, "financial year type: 0 - jan to dec, 1 - creation date plus 12 months");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so jooq introduced integerDisplayWidths property to cater for TINYINT(1) "types" in MySQL, which historically correspond to boolean types by convention. and this affected the behaviour of the above config. for it to work you have to make this property false.

```
    <integerDisplayWidths>false</integerDisplayWidths>
```

Comment: That's one approach. Another is to use a regex that would ignore everything that is after `TINYINT.*?`